# pm2 crashes with too many unstable restarts on scripts.sh

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, digital-ocean, pm2

I have some DigitalOcean droplet with small amount of RAM. I am writing my scripts in python and run this script using `pm2` like we run normally the node.js scripts but after some time the error displays like this. I do:

`pm2 start script.sh`

The app doesn't start and I get this repeated in the logs:

```
root@ubuntu-s-photomaths:/var/www/html/sym_math# pm2 logs
**[TAILING] Tailing last 15 lines for [all] processes (change the value with --lines option)
/root/.pm2/pm2.log last 15 lines:**
PM2        | 2019-12-11T04:29:23: PM2 log: App [script:0] online
PM2        | 2019-12-11T04:29:23: PM2 log: App [script:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2019-12-11T04:29:23: PM2 log: App [script:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2019-12-11T04:29:23: PM2 log: App [script:0] online
PM2        | 2019-12-11T04:29:24: PM2 log: App [script:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2019-12-11T04:29:24: PM2 log: App [script:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2019-12-11T04:29:24: PM2 log: App [script:0] online
PM2        | 2019-12-11T04:29:25: PM2 log: App [script:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2019-12-11T04:29:25: PM2 log: App [script:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2019-12-11T04:29:25: PM2 log: App [script:0] online
PM2        | 2019-12-11T04:29:26: PM2 log: App [script:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2019-12-11T04:29:26: PM2 log: App [script:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2        | 2019-12-11T04:29:26: PM2 log: App [script:0] online
PM2        | 2019-12-11T04:29:26: PM2 log: App [script:0] exited with code [0] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2        | 2019-12-11T04:29:26: PM2 log: Script /var/www/html/sym_math/script.sh had too many unstable restarts (16). Stopped. "errored"
****]
```

**my error logs can be display like this**

```
/root/.pm2/logs/script-error.log last 15 lines:
0|script   |
0|script   | Usage:
0|script   |  kill [options] <pid> [...]
0|script   |
0|script   | Options:
0|script   |  <pid> [...]            send signal to every <pid> listed
0|script   |  -<signal>, -s, --signal <signal>
0|script   |                         specify the <signal> to be sent
0|script   |  -l, --list=[<signal>]  list all signal names, or convert one to a name
0|script   |  -L, --table            list all signal names in a nice table
0|script   |
0|script   |  -h, --help     display this help and exit
0|script   |  -V, --version  output version information and exit
0|script   |
0|script   | For more details see kill(1).
```

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: You may need to tell PM2 your shell your interpreter or you my need to start python script in this way `pm2 start hello.py --interpreter=python3`

Comment: @caimaoy but i have installed only single version of python. it is 2.7 not multiple version of pythons.so by defult it can be run python 2.7 version.

Comment: Yeap, but it depends on what command in the shell and whether all the ENVS are right.

Comment: @caimaoy okay lets be check. if work that thanks but if not than i can try another way.

Comment: @caimaoy sorry sir it's not working